# Errors when rolling back to previous migration

Tags: django, django-migrations, django-1.9

Here is my current status:

```
mainapp
 [X] 0001_initial
 [X] 0002_authorprofile_uuid
 [X] 0003_auto_20151107_1243
 [X] 0004_article_approved
 [X] 0005_auto_20151129_0950
 [X] 0006_article_category
 [X] 0007_auto_20160501_1601
```

I want to go back to 0005. However, when I run `/manage.py migrate mainapp 0005_auto_20151129_0950` I get the error `ValueError: The database backend does not accept 0 as a value for AutoField.`

This is an error I've fixed in models.py, so I want to go back to 0005 and start fresh, and re-do the migrations.

```
class Article(models.Model):
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, default = 1) #trying to add this and set default value. It was first set to 0 but changed it to 1 after it failed
```

Comment: Sorry, now I have a better understanding of the real problem. After you change the field from Auto to a ForeignKey, you seem to have ended up inserting a 0 into that field. Mysql for example doesn't allow 0 in auto fields if you try to insert zero, it inserts the next auto increment value. So the problem is not in the code but data or that's what it seems to me.

Comment: @e4c5 basically 0007 thinks the field is in the database, but it's actually not. there's no column there. so if i change the default value, it can't because the column does not exist. if i try to drop the field, it can't because it doesn't exist

Comment: @e4c5 what if i just add a column via SQL commands and then migrate to drop it? then the drop will work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My suggestion is to open up your sql console and dump the `django_migrations` table.

```
DELETE FROM django_migrations WHERE app='mainapp'
```

Then make sure all your files in the migrations/ folder have been checked into version control and delete them! Then do

```
./manage.py makemigrations mainapp
./manage.py migrate mainapp --fake
```

If --fake doesn't work, it's time for desperate measure and `--fake-initial` but then it's very likely that when you deploy your app some where else you are going to have to go through this all process again :(